# why is require not working in javascript for mailchimp api

Tags: javascript, api, mailchimp

Not sure what I have done wrong, I am following the quick start guide for mailchimp developers. https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/quick-start/. I feel like I am missing a crucial step. I installed webpack. I am not getting the ping "everything is chimpy" instead its just perm reloading and highlighting requires in the sources tap in chrome dev tools.

It's highlighted 'require'.

```
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "7effff5342f8e4669e427c885b0b0088-us5",
  server: "us5",
});

async function run() {
  const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}

run();
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mail-chimp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing": "^3.0.70",
    "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "find-up": "^4.1.0",
    "locate-path": "^5.0.0",
    "npm-run-path": "^4.0.1",
    "onetime": "^5.1.2",
    "p-locate": "^4.1.0",
    "p-try": "^2.2.0",
    "path-exists": "^4.0.0",
    "path-key": "^3.1.1",
    "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
    "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
    "pkg-dir": "^4.2.0",
    "punycode": "^2.1.1",
    "randombytes": "^2.1.0",
    "resolve": "^1.20.0",
    "resolve-cwd": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve-from": "^5.0.0",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
    "shallow-clone": "^3.0.1",
    "shebang-regex": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.59.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem...?

Comment: SInce imports have changed for newer releases of node it maybe about that. Try `import mailchimp from '@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing'` or something along those lines.

Comment: says can't use it outside a module

Answer (score 0):

Just write this line of code :

```
import mailchimp from '@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing'
```

It will start working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).